# JSF2 how to disable doFilter when perform action listener?

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I now have troubles with Servlet filter. My problem is 
- I want to validate whenever users change url (type url, redirect,...) whereby I create a simple filter with Forward dispatcher. However, it leads to another problem
- I dont want to doFilter every time I perform 1 action. e.g: click a button. 
My method only satisfies the first trouble.
Do you have solutions for my problems? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the event source using the code below:

```
String[] eventSource = request.getParameterMap().get("javax.faces.source");
```

`eventSource[0]` here gives you the button id you set on xhtml.

so in `doFilter` method, you can do the following to simply get done with the filter, for that request:

```
if (eventSource != null && 
    eventSource.length > 0 &&
    eventSource[0].equals("myButtonId"))
{
    chain.doFilter();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but would you explain for me detail about your idea.

Comment: That 's the way, tt_emrah. I will try it later. And could you have solution to filter only when users change URL, so we could not have filter for action?

Comment: that's a different question, please ask another one for that.

Comment: Well, I tried another method. My only purpose is to only make filter when redirect the new address, so I stored every new address before perform any action in web page.